# How to get rid "count" from tooltip in Elasticsearch Kibana on coordinate map?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, geolocation, kibana, geomap

I load data from RESTful API to Elasticsearch and then visualized in Kibana as Coordinate map.

I did mapping on lat and long and Correctly streamed data to Kibana. In my coordinate map on top of the any point I can see tooltip which contains "count". I do not want to display this "count" on tooltip. I don't know how to remove it. Please any help fpr this?

I did coding in python client with Elasticsearch. I don't know whether I have to do in my code to remove this "Aggregatable" option. I searched in Kibana Cordinate Map tutorials, but didn't find any ways to remove this "count".

```
settings = {
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    'number_of_replicas': 0
  },
  "mappings": {
    "document": {
      "properties": {
        "geo": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

es.indices.create(index = "new", body = settings)

def collect_data():
  data = requests.get(url = URL).json()
  del data['positions'][1]
  new_data = {
  'geo': {
    'lat': data['positions'][0]['satlatitude'],
    'lon': data['positions'][0]['satlongitude']
  },
  'satname': data['info']['satname'],
  'satid': data['info']['satid'],
  'timestamp': datetime.fromtimestamp(data['positions'][0]['timestamp']).isoformat()

}

  es.index(index = 'new', doc_type = 'document', body = new_data)

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(collect_data)

while True:
  schedule.run_pending()
  time.sleep(1)
```

[image]

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo54K.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo54K.png)

[image]

Comment: Which version are you using? You can't remove it if you use the Kibana Coordinate Map, but you can if you the maps apps from version 7+ as per this [github issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/25565)

Comment: @leandrojmp, I'm using ES 6.4.3

Comment: @leandrojmp, I understood according to your link that I can't update this tooltip with  Coordinate map. But I don't understand the difference between this "Kibana Map" and "Elastic Maps" ? Pls can you tell me?

Comment: The coordinate map is just a type of Visualization in Kibana, basically Elastic improved the way you can create and use maps in Kibana and called it [Elastic Maps](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/maps.html) starting from version 7.